# Rolling hash hacking

Tags: hash, rolling-hash

The hash value of a string $s$ is given by

$$
h(s) = \sum^{|s|}_{i = 1} s_i  \cdot p^{|s| - i} \mod m;  \text{ $m$  is prime, $m < 10^{12}$}.
$$

The string $s$, $p$, $m$ is given,
 $|s| \le 14$, alphabet size $= 62$ (letters and digits).

I need to
find a string $s^{\prime}$:

$s^{\prime} \neq s$, but $h(s^{\prime}) = h(s)$

$s^{\prime}$ must meet the same requirements as $s$. The answer is always exist.

I know about Birthday-attack, but $m$ is too large and
if I generate random strings, probability of collision is too small.
Simple brute-force is also not suitable, because the string may be too long (14 characters).

Answer (score 1):

Running birthday attack should be faster than writing the question: sqrt(1e12) = 1e6

Also note that your question have nothing with *rolling* hashes, moreover, with rolling hash len(s) is fixed. So it may be that you missed some condtitions from the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write out the condition for $h(s)=h(s')$, expressed in terms of the variables $s_1,\dots,s_{14},s'_1,\dots,s'_{14}$.  Use linear algebra.